# Select rows where (a=1 and b=2 and c=3) and (a=2 and b=2 and c=2) etc

Tags: mysql

So I want to store the map of a game into my database, which consists out of let's say galaxies, systems and positions. My table looks like this:

```
id | galaxy | system | position | other information ...
1  | 1      | 1      | 1        | blahblah
2  | 1      | 1      | 2        | blahblah
3  | 1      | 1      | 3        | blahblah
4  | 1      | 1      | 4        | blahblah
5  | 2      | 111    | 6        | blahblah
```

What I want to do is to select multiple rows with their coordinates, so let's say `WHERE galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position = 1` and `WHERE galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position = 2`. It should be possible somehow but I couldn't find a solution, or I'm just searching with the wrong keywords since I don't really know how to phrase my problem.

Comment: You might want to learn the difference between `and` and `or`. You want it to match either the first cooridnates OR the second.

Comment: How about `WHERE galaxy = system = position`?

Comment: @Ivar Actually I want the rows with _both_ coordinates. So in my example I want the rows with the IDs 1 and 2.

Comment: That is impossible. You can't have one row with position 1 and position 2. You want the first **and** the second row, but it should match a condition where it should be match position 1 **or** position 2.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Your first comment was right ofcourse @Ivar. Do you want to post an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? :P

Comment: It's fine. No need to add another answer. (There are probably already dozens of duplicates of this question, though it is hard to find them)

Comment: But why so complicated - why not simply what I suggested (in my comment and now as an answer)?

Comment: Because I'm not trying to select rows with the same value for those 3 rows. See my comment to your answer. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ivar is correct:

```
WHERE
   (galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position = 1) OR 
   (galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position = 2)
```

Is the general form

In this EXACT example, you can `OR` the `positions`:

```
WHERE
   galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position IN (1,2)
```

It would do you good to learn about `AND` and `OR` of conditions.

Comment: Thank you, this works. It's been a long time since I used MySQL and I was somehow thinking that `OR` would result into only the first row matching one of the conditions.

Comment: The `IN` works fine in this case, though it gets messy when you have multiple galaxies for example as it matches all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways you can filter. try to understand `in` clause and how to use `or` and `braces()`

Method 1

```
WHERE (galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position = 1) 
or (galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position = 2)
```

Method 2

```
 WHERE galaxy = 1 AND system = 1 AND position in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works and is easier if you are just simply looking for all rows where those fields have the same values:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `galaxy` = `system` = `position`;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I'm not looking for rows where those fields have the same values. I was just looking for a way to select multiple rows with different combinations of coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the IN() function

For example:

```
SELECT * from YOURTABLE where galaxy in(1) and system in(1) and position in(1,2)
```

What this does is to select all rows from your table where galaxy equals '1' and system equals '1' and position equals '1' or '2'